# How to output Django queryset as JSON?

Tags: json, django, listview, django-queryset

I want to serialize my queryset, and I want it in a format as this view outputs:

```
class JSONListView(ListView):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': [['bar','foo','bar','foo'],['foo','bar','foo','bar']]}, indent=4), content_type='application/json')
```

I simply don't know how to output the queryset instead of the manual data in the example.

I've tried

```
json.dumps({"data": self.get_queryset()})
```

and

```
serializers.serialize("json", {'data': self.get_queryset()})
```

but it won't work. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to make a custom JSON Encoder?

Comment: What didn't work? Have you read [the docs on serialising querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)? I'd imagine the problem is with ForeignKey/M2M relationships within your model

Answer (score 172):

You can use [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) with [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values). Simple example:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_view(request):
    data = list(SomeModel.objects.values())  # wrap in list(), because QuerySet is not JSON serializable
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)  # or JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

Or another approach with [Django's built-in serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/#serializing-data):

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    qs = SomeModel.objects.all()
    qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', qs)
    return HttpResponse(qs_json, content_type='application/json')
```

In this case result is slightly different (without indent by default):

```
[
    {
        "model": "some_app.some_model",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "name": "Elon",
            "age": 48,
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

I have to say, it is good practice to use something like [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/) to serialize queryset.

...and a few notes for better performance:

- use pagination if your queryset is big;
- use `objects.values()` to specify list of required fields to avoid serialization and sending to client unnecessary model's fields (you also can pass `fields` to `serializers.serialize`);

Comment: Using `JsonResponse` with JSON is incorrect, `HttpResponse` should be used instead. If using

Comment: i don't like Django model format with specific fileds `{model: "name.sub", pk: 1, fields: {,…}}`. I like [simple JSON with it's own fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30243413/4854931).

Comment: @Alex78191 thank you, you are right. I expected that Django's serializers work in the same way as DRF serializers.

Comment: sorry for the rand, but this is so much complication for returning very basic data

Comment: @vladimir.gorea there are only 3-4 lines of code + imports in every example.

Comment: @MarkMishyn I was referring to the Django serializers. I just want some variable with simple json-ized data. Probably a look to serialize yourself is easier.

Comment: Option#1 of Mark Mishyn's answer is the best option when using DRF.

Comment: @AwsAnurag, DRF has it's own serializers and Response class, so you don't need use Django's Json Response or values_list.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks yes but there are certain limitations when using custom User model where your first option is a quicker approach to return a GET response without violating Django rules. This is of course my personal preference and I am sure there are better ways out there. I up-voted your answer because I am sure this will help others who are not aware of such better ways. Thank again. :-)

Comment: What is `SomeModel`?

Comment: @BrianWiley it's a instance of django.db.Model

Answer (score 44):

It didn't work, because QuerySets are not JSON serializable.

1) In case of `json.dumps` you have to explicitely convert your QuerySet to JSON serializable objects:

```
class Model(model.Model):
    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            # other stuff
        }
```

And the serialization:

```
dictionaries = [ obj.as_dict() for obj in self.get_queryset() ]
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data": dictionaries}), content_type='application/json')
```

2) In case of serializers. Serializers accept either JSON serializable object or QuerySet, but a dictionary containing a QuerySet is neither. Try this:

```
serializers.serialize("json", self.get_queryset())
```

Read more about it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

Comment: That's a good answer. I will go with the first solution. In your second solution, how is it possible to assign a 'key' to the data?

Should it be something like {"data": serializers.serialize("json", self.get_queryset())}?

Comment: @user2232982 I'm not sure to be honest, I'm always using first technique. :) Your solution is not good, because you get a dictionary with a JSON string so you still need to serialize it resulting in double serialized object. :O

Comment: The first tehnique is an invention of the wheel.

Answer (score 24):

For a efficient solution, you can use [.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) function to get a list of dict objects and then dump it to json response by using i.e. [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) (remember to set `safe=False`).

Once you have your desired queryset object, transform it to JSON response like this:

```
...
data = list(queryset.values())
return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

You can specify field names in `.values()` function in order to return only wanted fields (the example above will return all model fields in json objects).

Answer (score 10):

To return the queryset you retrieved with `queryset = Users.objects.all(),` you first need to serialize them.

Serialization is the process of converting one data structure to another. Using Class-Based Views, you could return JSON like this.

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class JSONListView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = User.objects.all()
        data = serialize("json", qs)
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

This will output a list of JSON. For more detail on how this works, check out my blog article [How to return a JSON Response with Django](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-return-a-json-response-in-django/). It goes into more detail on how you would go about this.

Comment: i don't believe this outputs a JSON string.  I believe you end up with a bytes object, so this is not a very useful solution unless you mean to only send JSON back to the client.

Answer (score 5):

If the goal is to build an API that allow you to access your models in JSON format I recommend you to use the `django-restframework` that is an enormously popular package within the Django community to achieve this type of tasks.

- [Django Rest Framework Website](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)
- [Github](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework)

It include useful features such as Pagination, Defining Serializers, Nested models/relations and more. Even if you only want to do minor Javascript tasks and Ajax calls I would still suggest you to build a proper API using the Django Rest Framework instead of manually defining the JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to turn queryset into JSON, is appending necessary elements to an empty list with loop. It provides to design customizable JSON.

```
queryset = Users.objects.all()
output = []
for query in queryset:
   output.append('id': query.id, 'name': query.name, etc...)
return JSONResponse(output, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending serializers.Serializer is the way to go really however for some reason if you really don't want to then the following should give you some json from query set.

```
from django.core import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
    
peoples = People.objects.all()
data = serializers.serialize('json', peoples)
json_data = json.loads(data)
return Response(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on some responses, I ended up creating a template filter:

```
# your-app/templatetags/your-file.py
from django.core import serializers

@register.filter
def json(data):
    return serializers.serialize('json', data)
```

The template filter accepts a queryset. You could just pass `YourModel.objects.all()`

```
{# your-app/templates/your-app/your-template.html #}
<script>
    let data = {{ rows|json|safe }}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class JSONListView(ListView):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        data["users"] = get_json_list(queryset)
        return JSONResponse(data)


def get_json_list(query_set):
    list_objects = []
    for obj in query_set:
        dict_obj = {}
        for field in obj._meta.get_fields():
            try:
                if field.many_to_many:
                    dict_obj[field.name] = get_json_list(getattr(obj, field.name).all())
                    continue
                dict_obj[field.name] = getattr(obj, field.name)
            except AttributeError:
                continue
        list_objects.append(dict_obj)
    return list_objects
```

Comment: Giving code out and doing others job for them, without explaining the original problem and the solution used, doesn't help much...

Answer (score -3):

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def SomeFunction():
       dict1 = {}

       obj = list( Mymodel.objects.values() )

       dict1['data']=obj

return JsonResponse(dict1)
```

Try this code for Django