# Django - Return JSON, Error

Tags: django, json, mongodb

I got a View.py function that looks like this:

```
def GetAllCities(request):

cities = list(City.objects.all())
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(cities))
```

My City model looks like this

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField()
    loc = models.CharField()
    population = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField()
    _id = models.CharField()

    class MongoMeta:
        db_table = "cities"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city
```

I am using a MongoDB that looks like this

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5179837cbd7fe491c1f23227"),
   "city" : "ACMAR",
   "loc" : "[-86.51557, 33.584132]",
   "state" : "AL",
   "population" : 6055
}
```

I get the following error when trying to return the JSON from my GetAllCities function:

**City ACMAR is not JSON serializable**

So I tried this Instead:

```
def GetAllCities(request):

    cities = serializers.serialize("json", City.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(cities)
```

And this works but It's very slow, it takes about 9 seconds(My database contains 30000 rows)
Should it take this long or am I doing something wrong?
I've built the same app in PHP, Rails and NodeJS.
In PHP it takes on average 2000ms, NodeJS = 800ms, Rails = 5882ms and Django 9395ms. Im trying to benchmark here so I wonder if there is a way to optimize my Django code or is this as fast as it gets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOUND A SOLUTION**

I am benchmarking with different methods, one method is to see how fast one language/framework is to select ALL rows in a database and return it as JSON. I found a solution now that speeds it up by half the time!

**My new views.py**

```
def GetAllCities(request):

    dictionaries = [ obj.as_dict() for obj in City.objects.all() ]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"Cities": dictionaries}), content_type='application/json')
```

**And my new model**

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField()
    loc = models.CharField()
    population = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField()
    _id = models.CharField()
def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "city": self.city,
            "loc": self.loc,
            "population": self.population,
            "state": self.state
            # other stuff
        }

    class MongoMeta:
         db_table = "cities"

def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city
```

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

1. For sure you do not need to return ALL cities, as you probably won't display all 30000 rows anyway (at least in user-friendly way). Consider a solution where you return only cities within some range from requested location. Mongo supports [geospatial indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/), so there should be no problem in doing that. There are also many tutorials over the internet how to perform spatial filtering in Django/MongoDB.

   ```
   def GetAllCities(request, lon, lat):

       #Pseudo-code
       cities = City.objects.filterWithingXkmFromLonLat(lon, lat).all() 

       cities = serializers.serialize("json", cities) 
       return HttpResponse(cities)
   ```
2. If you really, really need all cities, consider caching the response. Location, name and population of cities are not things which change dynamically, in a matter of let's say seconds. Cache the result and recalculate only every hour, day or more. Django supports cache [out of the box](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/)

   ```
   @cache_page(60 * 60)
   def GetAllCities(request):
      (...)
   ```

Comment: This is a really good answer, but I'm benchmarking, see my answer :)

Comment: Even if you cut the processing time you actually haven't solved the problem. If you'll have two times more cities the time will be two times bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try to get a little more of speed is to get from db just the values you need and get the QuerySet to build the dictionary.

A simple query like this would work:

```
City.objects.all().values('id', 'city', 'loc', 'population', 'state')
```

Or you can put it in a manager:

```
class CitiesManager(models.Manager):

    class as_dict(self):
        return self.all().values('id', 'city', 'loc', 'population', 'state')

class City(models.Model):
    .... your fields here...

    objects = CitiesManager()
```

And then use it in your view as:

```
City.objects.as_dict()
```

Comment: Aaah very nice, vill try that! Thank you