# Is there any way convert Django model queryset to json or json string in template?

Tags: django

I want to combine react (or vue) with django template, but I don't want to change the backend to restful api. So I wonder is there any way convert Django model queryset to json or json string in template, so that I can fetch the data from dom used in jsx or vue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output Django queryset as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use just the [serialization](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) component of [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). It provides a declarative serializer that is more flexible than the one in Django.

An added benefit, if/when you want to provide a full restful API you'll already have a good hunk of the code for it written.

Answer (score 5):

To serialize a `Django` queryset with core functionality take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/):

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from models import MyModel

serialize('json', MyModel.objects.all())
```

In order to access the `JSON` in your template, without using a `REST API` resource or `AJAX`, take advantage of [custom template tags/filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/).

`tags.py`:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter
def json(queryset):
    return serialize('json', queryset)
```

HTML Template:

```
{% load tags %}
{% users|json %}
```