# Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable Django

Tags: python, json, django, ajax

When I am trying to send values in JsonResponse then The error is coming(object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable )

```
def ajaxAgent(request):
    data = CommCenter.objects.values()
    responseData = { 'status': 'success', 'msg' : data}
    return JsonResponse(responseData)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output Django queryset as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json) the answer:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_view(request):
    data = list(SomeModel.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)  # or JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was using `values_list()` and converting to list using `list`

```
def ajaxAgent(request):
    data = CommCenter.objects.filter().values_list()
    responseData = { 'status': 'success', 'msg' : list(data)}
    return JsonResponse(responseData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a model serializer to serialize the values of the objects into JSON that are returned to you as list when you fetch objects using Django ORM. Check this link out for more details [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)