# django dict/queryset/list to json

Tags: json, django, dictionary, django-queryset, django-orm

[image]

I want to convert this queryset to json.

[image]

json.dumps() does not work.

[image]

serialize does not work.

[image]

json.dumps() + list() does not work

how can I convert querset to json?
maybe the reason these conversions are not work is in here.
[image]

I know that
Models.objects.all() or Models.objects.all().only() return queryset,
Models.objects.all().values() returns list of dict.

I want to add a new key-value set to the first queryset,
So I use Models.objects.all().values()

but when I add a new key-value set, I think, the datatype is twisted.
so now the datatype of 'questionRequeestList' is neither 'List' nor 'Queryset' at converting to json.

how can I convert this value to json?
or how can I add new queryset to another queryset dict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output Django queryset as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json)

Comment: I already read that comment and did, It did not work..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, using Django's query operations, such as the filter () method, returns a query set object. This is an object that can't use JSON. Dumps () directly, because the parameter needed to change the method is a dictionary, not a query set object. Here is a suggestion: use a loop to take out every element in the query set, and then use the modified method to convert it to JSON data.

Example:
a = list
for i in questionRequeestList:
     a= a.append(json.dumps(i))

Comment: Wow.. Though I thought about it for a while, I knew there was a way I didn't know. that was the best way...