# How to retrieve all data from foreign keys with Django ORM and return them as JsonResponse

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to get all the data from a model and its foreign keys and I have a hard time using select_related() and values() or values_list().
I got an Order table who got two foreign keys. I need to query all the data and send it as a JsonResponse. This is the line:
`Order.objects.select_related('persoana_fizica__persoana_juridica').values()`
I saw I can write inside values what fields I need, I am looking for a method to select all of them without writing every single one, '**all**' didn't worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output Django queryset as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json)

Comment: I understand how I can turn data intro JSON, but still, I don't know how to get all data from all foreign keys without writing every single field inside values()