# Query set is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create an endpoint but I keep getting an error: "Object of type model is not JSON serializable".

I tried passing it through `list()` and `json.dumps()` but it int work. I tried printing the query and it was like

```
[<Lead: Test>, <Lead: user2>, <Lead: user3>, <Lead: user4>]
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
def leads(request):
    full = []
    lead_list = list(Lead.objects.all())
    print(lead_list)
    for i in lead_list:
        full.append(json.dumps(i))
    print(full)
    return JsonResponse(list(full), safe=False)
```

Here are a few question I looked at and tried:

[Output Django queryset as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json)

I tried serializing it with serializer but the response was like this:

```
"[{\"model\": \"leads.lead\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"first_name\": \"Test\", \"last_name\": \"User\", \"age\": 25, \"city\": \"kolkata\", \"country\": \"India\", \"email\": \"ankr@gmail.com\", \"agent\": 1, \"status\": \"Potential\"}}, {\"model\": \"leads.lead\", \"pk\": 2, \"fields\": {\"first_name\": \"user2\", \"last_name\": \"test2\", \"age\": 44, \"city\": \"Mumbai\", \"country\": \"India\", \"email\": \"test2@gmail.com\", \"agent\": null, \"status\": \"prospect\"}}, {\"model\": \"leads.lead\", \"pk\": 4, \"fields\": {\"first_name\": \"user3\", \"last_name\": \"test3\", \"age\": 19, \"city\": \"Paris\", \"country\": \"France\", \"email\": \"test3@gmail.com\", \"agent\": null, \"status\": \"Prospect\"}}, {\"model\": \"leads.lead\", \"pk\": 8, \"fields\": {\"first_name\": \"user4\", \"last_name\": \"test4\", \"age\": 33, \"city\": \"London\", \"country\": \"UK\", \"email\": \"test4@gmail.com\", \"agent\": null, \"status\": \"Converted\"}}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to `serialize` your queryset then use `JsonResponse`.

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'

def leads(request):
    qs= Lead.objects.all()
    serializer = LeadSerializer(qs,many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

PS: since i don't know the columns in your `Lead` Model i am using `ModelSerializer` for serializing, However you can write your own custom serializer using `serializers.Serializer` also by mentioning your each column like

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializer.CharField(max_length=10)
    column_1 = serializer.IntegerField()
```

Comment: I tired it but is shows` [OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict()]`

Comment: I have edited the answer, I had forgot to add class meta in serializer and mapping it with the model. I have tried it myself and it is returning me desired values