# How do I pass a QuerySet from python to js?

Tags: javascript, django, django-queryset

So I'm currently working in Django and I wanted to grab data from my database and use it in my js script. This is what I'm trying to pass into js, `stockhist=StockHistory.objects.filter(user_id=x).values()`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the queryset to JSON as described [in the first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/output-django-queryset-as-json) and return the results in your API response.

Depending on the nature of your project, you may also want to learn more about Django Rest Framework's [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out but had a hard time getting a dictionary instead of the sting I was getting when I used

````
```stockhist=(StockHistory.objects.filter(user_id=x))
hist=serialize('json',stockhist)```
````

A lucky guess led me to the right answer when I change the json to python like this

````
```stockhist=(StockHistory.objects.filter(user_id=x))
hist=serialize('python',stockhist)```
````

For those wondering how I called it in my html this is what I did

````
```{{ hist|json_script:"Hist" }}```
````

and I called it in my js like this

`var performanceHist = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('Hist').textContent)`