# Using for django loop inside of a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.8

I want to loop through a django query in JavaScript, example: musics = Music.query.all().

I did something like this:

```
const songs = [
{% for music in musics %}
    {
        id: "{{music.id }}",
        songName: "{{ music.title }}",
        poster: "{{ music.cover_image.url }}",
    }
{% endfor %}
]
 Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("songItem")).forEach((element, I) =>{
  element.getElementsByTagName('img').src = songs[I].poster;
})
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'poster'),

but if I use console log

```
console.log(element.getElementsByTagName('img').src = songs[I].poster);
```

it works in the console.

Comment: Is this a javascript file or javascript written inside a <script> tag within a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `,` in your foor loop. Therefore you are getting a syntax error.

```
const songs = [
  {% for music in musics %}
    {id: "{{music.id }}",
     songName: "{{ music.title}}",
     poster: "{{music.cover_image.url}}",
    }, // <-- HERE 
  {% endfor %}
]
```

If you want to convert your object data to json, you could also do this in your view and pass the json date as a template variable instead of creating `songs` manually.

Comment: I pass the song query through django template json like: ``{{ music|json_scripts: 'musics' }}`` how do i loop though the data

Comment: If you are serializing `musics` to json in your view, you do not have to loop through it in javascript. You could just do `const songs = {{ musics }}`. You can read more about serializing models [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37839240/15353043). Does the for loop work when you are inserting the `,`?

Comment: Thanks, have done it using the looping, just tried different approach and it worked