# Respond an array of json objects in Django view

Tags: python, django

I have this table or model:

| longitude | latitude | session |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 1 |
| 99 | 42 | 2 |
| 99 | 42 | 1 |
| 99 | 42 | 3 |
| 99 | 42 | 1 |
| 99 | 42 | 2 |

I need to make a query to get all data by session. So I get all the data from the table and apply 'distinct' to get the sessions:

```
sessions= GPSData.objects.values('session_new_id').distinct()
```

I get:

```
<QuerySet [{'session': 1}, {'session': 2}, 'session': 3}]>
```

Now, for each session I need to get longitude an latitude. Afterwards I need to send an HttpResponse with the data in a JSON. So I'm trying in my view:

```
def get_all_gps(request):
    data=[]   
    for session in sessions:
        y=GPSData.objects.filter(session=session['session'])
        y = serializers.serialize("json", y)
        data.append(y)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

I get an error in the template because I am passing an array not a json object:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 190986 of the JSON data
```

In general what I need is to respond with an array of JSON objects. Something like this:

```
[[{json from session 1}],[{json from session 2}],[{json from session 3}]]
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output Django queryset as JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/how-to-output-django-queryset-as-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874233/how-to-output-django-queryset-as-json) @Mike Jones has commented and was able to do it using `JsonResponse`.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import GPSData

def get_all_gps(request):
    data = []   
    for gps_data in GPSData.objects.all().order_by("session").values():
        try:
            session_list = next(l for l in data if l[0]["session"] == gps_data["session"])
        except StopIteration:
            session_list = []
            data.append(session_list)
        session_list.append(gps_data)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```