# How do I manipulate a Django dictionary in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary called cards, which I have created from my Card model. Each card has a front and back property. I think I am importing the 'cards' dictionary into my JS file from the template correctly. But I am unsure on how to access the vales from the dictionary, and how to display the values without any {,[,' etc.

I did previously try having 2 different arrays: one for the fronts of the cards, one of the backs of the cards. However, I have a feeling this could get messy later on. Either way, it would be useful to know how to display python dictionaries in JS.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Deck(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Card(models.Model):
    front = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    back = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cards')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.front
```

view function:

```
def learn(request, deck_id):
    deck = get_object_or_404(Deck, pk=deck_id)
    cards_queryset = deck.cards.all()
    cards = [{'front': card.front, 'back': card.back} for card in cards_queryset]
    
    
    return render(request, 'srs/learn.html', {
        'deck': deck,
        'cards': cards,
    })
```

template file:

```
{% extends "srs/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="body-container">
        <p class="front"></p>
        <p class="back"></p>
        <button id="show-answer">Show Answer</button>
        <button id="next-card">Next</button>

    </div>

    <div id="cards-var" data-cards="{{ cards }}"></div>
    <script src="{% static 'srs/learn.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript cannot load neither a QuerySet nor a Python Dict. As our friend kindly pointed out, you need to transform data to a format that JavaScript is able to load, in this case JSON.

You can use [`model_to_dict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/_modules/django/forms/models/) form helper function to extract the wanted fields instead of doing it manually, also making the code more readable.

views.py

```py
from django.forms import model_to_dict
import json


def learn(request, deck_id):
    deck = get_object_or_404(Deck, pk=deck_id)
    qs = deck.cards.all()
    cards = [model_to_dict(instance, fields=["front", "back"]) for instance in qs]

    return render(
        request,
        "srs/learn.html",
        {
            "deck": deck,
            "cards": json.dumps(cards),
        },
    )
```

srs/learn.js

```js
document.getElementById("show-answer").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const data = document.getElementById("cards-var").dataset.cards;
  const cards = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(cards[0]);
});
```

Template remains the same.

An alternative would be to use Django [`serialization`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects). Here is an [`example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37839240/7100120).

Comment: Cheers to both of you guys it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Django has anything specific for this, but you can always:

1. Define the data model you are working with in your JS
2. `json.dumps(your_dict)` from python and return the resulting string
3. `json.parse(resulting_str)` the string into the object you modeled in JS

This should give you a javascript object.

Just remember that json.parse() can throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Since both of your models `Deck` and `Card` don't have datetime field, It can be easily serialized.

You can use **JsonResponse** module [refer here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.JsonResponse) where it sends json as a response for the corresponding request.

you can modify your view like below,

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def learn(request, deck_id):
    deck = get_object_or_404(Deck, pk=deck_id)
    cards_queryset = deck.cards.all()
    cards = [{'front': card.front, 'back': card.back} for card in cards_queryset]
     
    return JsonResponse({
        'deck': deck,
        'cards': cards,
    },safe=False, status=200)
```

you can access the json in JS by using `fetch` API,

in `srs/learn.js`:

```js
let card_details = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('<your corresponding Django URL for the learn fn>');
  const data = await response.json();
  return JSON.parse(data);
};
```

Now you can display card_details (which is now JS object) in your required block.